# How to add value in select option (simple_form rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple array :

```
@fields = %w(full_name name pseudo).map{ |key| I18n.t("users.security.#{key}", locale: :en) }
```

In a collection form, I would like to get an integer (like array index).

```
        <%= f.input :display_name,
                    :as => :select,
                    :collection => @fields,
                    %>
```

displayed as :

```
 <option selected="selected" value=0>full name</option>
 <option value=1>name</option>
 <option value=2>pseudo</option>
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array of arrays of length 2 that contains the option value and the option display name.

As you already have an array with the display name, you can construct the necessary array as follows:

```
f.input :display_name,
  as: :select,
  collection: @fields.map.with_index { |v, i| [i, v] }
```

Comment: Great... ;)  Thanks